# Drupal content type with image and title

Tags: drupal, media, content-type

I have problem to create a content type with an image and a name. I need to create a content type with multiple images and titles. The result are many people's photos with the name above the pictures.
How I can resolve it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly great example image :)

But what I think you should do is have 1 content type with 2 fields - Title and Image. Lets call this content type 'people'.

Each person should be a created separately as a different node.

Then you can use the [views module](https://drupal.org/project/views) to show all the people on one page.

I think having each person as a separate entity will be more flexible as it would allow you to relate each person to other entities and make the whole system more extendable.

If for some reason you really do want to attach all people to one node then you could use the [field collection module](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection). This would enable you to create a field collection called people. The field collection would have a field for title and image, and then you would attach multiple people to one node that way.

[image]

Comment: maybe i'll try to use the second solution. Because for my problem I should repeat many times the first solution. Thanks for your time :).

Comment: The field collection seems working

Answer (score 0):

You should try with field collection fields which allows you to add multiple set of names & images associated with each of them. Then using panels & views, you can display them in the grid. You should learn documentation of panels & views first